# how can I limit a user to input 8 characters into string(dynamic char array)in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int size;
cout<<"enter string size"<<endl;
cin>>size;
char * string1 = new char[size];
```

well hello,im working on a project and one of my functions purpose is to get a dynamic char array as arg which sends to the output the first letters of the words in the string.
so the user decides the string length (for the initialized dynamic array),
but then how can i ensure he won't exceed the length of the array he chose?(the compiler does not Refer to it as a mistake).
can i force the 'cin' operator to limit itself?

Comment: *"get a dynamic char array"* is not a meaningful purpose. You should not use `new[]`. Change your code to use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` before you proceed.

Comment: and why is that?

Comment: A very strange question, because that's the *normal* thing to do in C++. It's normal because it's better, safer, easier, faster, more professional, exception-safe, less to type and less to read; it makes strings or containers as naturally easy to use as `int`s. The question is: Why would you use `new[]`?

Comment: well i need a function that gets as arg dynamic string which can be initialized only by char array isnt it?

Comment: No. If that "dynamic string" is a `char const*`, then use the `c_str()` member function of `std::string`.

Comment: im new to c++ ,so i understands that a string variable is a hidden char array which acts also as a pointer.so i was told to take in a dynamic string, which has to be a char array no? i mean is there any meaning for a dynamic string? i don't think so because even if i limit it by size(input os user), the user can still input more characters then the size of it when it was initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `std::string` is better, but...

```
char input [8];
cin.getline (input, 8);
```

Note, there may still be data in the input buffer after this that you may need to deal with.

**Edit**

Given the original code in the question:

```
cin.getline(string1, size);
```

Comment: plus 1 for cin.getline, but OP is asking for a dynamic char array.

Comment: Replace `input` with `string1` and `8` with `size`

Comment: You can't replace a statically declared array's size with a variable value.

Comment: That's not what I meant -- I just meant taking exactly the code from OP....  I'll edit to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just have them input into a `std::string`. Don't bother with the manual memory management.

```
std::cout << "Enter your name.\n> ";
std::string name;
std::cin >> name;
```

Then, if you need to only pass the first 8 characters or something, use `name.substr(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to be std::string, but if you really want to use a character array, you should use:

```
 cin.getline(string1, 8);
```

This gets 8 characters from the user input.

cin getline works as followed:

It extracts characters, without any formatting and storms them as an c-string. It will stop extracting characters when either the new line character is reached, a set char deliminator, or until the number of characters specified has been extracted.

Answer (score -1):

You can make this approach with `std::string`. For example:

```
const int maxchar = 8;
string str;
cin >> str;

if (str.size() > maxchar )
{
   err << "The input is too long." << endl;
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but the question was about limiting user input to a number of characters.